# Visualization vs. visualizations

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

I have the following sentence:

> Create an interactive web-based data visualization using Python.

I'm wondering what is the correct way to write this sentence in the plural, since visualization is uncountable. Is

> Create interactive web-based data visualizations using Python.

correct?

What I mean is that I built some graphics using Python.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you think visualization is uncountable?

Answer (score 1):

Visualization is used in a countable sense here.  The quote has "an... visualization". Nouns used with a singular article are countable.

The meaning of "a visualization" is "A visual representation of data." (wiktionary)  Usually a visualisation is a graph or chart.

As a countable noun, it has a (regular) plural "visualizations".

Comment: Would "Create interactive web-based data visualization using Python." have been wrong?

Comment: That would be the uncountable sense meaning "The act of visualizing".  Python may be able to `import antigravity` but it can't actually intialise the process of forming images in your mind!  So that is a mistake.

Comment: Thank you. Just the last question: in this case "Created" is the more appropriate verb or can "Built" also be good?